# Typescript and VS2013: How to force build despite ts errors

Tags: visual-studio-2013, compilation, typescript

I am getting some mysterious compiler type related errors in my ts code. I have another thread addressing them.

But I know there will be no adverse reactions to my code, so I would like to force it to compile and make my js files anyway so I can do some run-time debugging.

I have seen a comment or two about the project compiling despite some build errors. How do I do that? If I use the command line compiler it seems to do this, but apparently I am spoiled VS programmer who wants a to build in one step, not two.

I have VS2013 and TS 1.5.

Thanks, Brad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I do that? If I use the command line compiler it seems to do this, but apparently I am spoiled VS programmer who wants a to build in one step, not two.

Make sure that in your csproj you have `noEmitOnError` set to `false`.

Comment: That worked! My vbproj file did not have that line so I added this: <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>false</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError> to the first <PropertyGroup> section.